# Pandas: How do I insert DataFrame columns in another column with the resulting MultiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas

I got the following data structure for object 1:

```
dayofweek  A  B  C
Monday     1  2  3
Tuesday    4  5  6
```

All those items `A, B, C` I got for other objects, let's say `Obj1`. `Obj2`, `Obj3`.

I wanna put all the date in one dataframe with the MultiIndex columns structure:

```
object        Obj1      Obj2      Obj3
dayofweek  A  B  C   A  B  C   A  B  C
Monday     1  2  3   2  1  3   3  2  1
Tuesday    4  5  6   5  4  6   6  5  4
```

How can I do it easily? I tried to use `.unstack()`, but it puts objects' label below `A, B, C` columns

Answer (score 2):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `keys` parameter for `MultiIndex` with `rename` columns:

```
df = df.set_index('dayofweek')
df1 = df.rename(columns={'A':'B', 'B':'A'}).sort_index(axis=1)
df2 = df.rename(columns={'A':'C', 'C':'A'}).sort_index(axis=1)

df3 = pd.concat([df, df1, df2], keys=('Obj1','Obj2','Obj3'), axis=1)
print (df3)

          Obj1       Obj2       Obj3      
             A  B  C    A  B  C    A  B  C
dayofweek                                 
Monday       1  2  3    2  1  3    3  2  1
Tuesday      4  5  6    5  4  6    6  5  4
```

If there are 3 DataFrames with `dayofweek` column use:

```
dfs = [df, df1, df2]
df3 = pd.concat([x.set_index('dayofweek') for x in dfs], keys=('Obj1','Obj2','Obj3'), axis=1)
print (df3)
```

Comment: This is nice. If we have the 'dayofweek' column in all 3 dfs, how will this work

Comment: @jezrael nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use merge:

```
print(obj1.merge(obj2, on='dayofweek').merge(obj3, on='dayofweek'))
```

result:

```
  dayofweek  A_x  B_x  C_x  A_y  B_y  C_y  A  B  C
0    Monday    1    2    3    2    1    3  3  2  1
1   Tuesday    4    5    6    5    4    6  6  5  4
```

Comment: there is no MultiIndex.